# Eglot toggle flymake diagnostics with keyboard shortcut

Tags: lsp, eglot, flymake

I've successfully got eglot working, and I love using it for things like xref in my rust projects. As I'm writing code, I don't like having diagnostics pop up as I'm typing, but sometimes I'd like to choose to run / see diagnostics.

I'm able to disable flymake in eglot with the following configuration:

```
(use-package eglot
  :ensure t
  :hook
  ;; Disable flymake by default. Can enable with ~M-x flymake-mode~
  (eglot-managed-mode . (lambda () (flymake-mode -1)))
  :config
  ;; When using xref, still have eglot active in the followed location
  (setq eglot-extend-to-xref t)
  (add-to-list 'eglot-server-programs
               '((rust-ts-mode rust-mode) .
                 ("rust-analyzer" :initializationOptions (:check (:command "clippy"))))))
```

This works until I want to enable diagnostics.

I am able to re-enable it with `M-x flymake-mode` in a buffer. However, if I try to disable it again, using `M-x flymake-mode` something about the configuration is sticky, and diagnostics start showing up again when I save the buffer. After that point, I'm unable to disable diagnostics without restarting eglot.

What I would like is the ability to turn diagnostics on and off in a single buffer with a function / key command reliably. Is that something that is possible with eglot & flymake?